# How do I create a data source that connects to a 32-bit driver on a 64-bit platform?

Tags: odbc

I have some old VB6 code that requires an ODBC data source and I'm trying to run it on Windows 7 64-bit but I get this error:

System.ApplicationException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer:

- To manage a data source that connects to a 32-bit driver under 64-bit platform, use c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.
- To manage a data source that connects to a 64-bit driver, use c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe.

More info @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712362(v=vs.85).aspx